# Intercepting Sprout Forms "onSaveEntry" Event In Craft 3 Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, plugin-sproutforms

I've built lots of Craft 2 plugins that catch Sprout Forms submissions and integrate with external services (CRM's etc). It was easy, you'd make a plugin and catch the event going:

```
craft()->on('sproutForms.onSaveEntry', function(SproutForms_OnSaveEntryEvent $event) {
    // Hand submission off to your service to do some rad stuff.
});
```

But in Craft 3, that events functionality appears to be more complicated. All the [Events & Hooks area in the Sprout Documentation](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/docs/forms/events-and-hooks.html) just show "Example needed." in all the places where code samples would usually be. The [Craft 3 plugin docs on events](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/updating-plugins.html#events) show a new system for registering and intercepting events - but my coffee deficient mind is struggling to figure out how to map that to Craft3/Sprout Forms 3.0.0-beta.17.

Has anyone built a Craft 3 plugin that works with Sprout Forms Beta yet? I'm even struggling to find examples of any event integration in plugins at the moment.

Halp!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated the Sprout docs with [examples of Craft 3 events and hooks](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/docs/forms/events-and-hooks.html).

In your case, the Form Entry Element extends the `craft\base\Element` class and also supports the same after the base element save event: `EVENT_AFTER_SAVE`. In your primary plugin class `init` method:

```
use barrelstrength\sproutforms\elements\Entry;
use yii\base\Event;
use Craft;

public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    Event::on(Entry::class, Entry::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE, function(Event $event) {
        if (Craft::$app->request->isSiteRequest)
        {
            // A Form Entry Element has been saved from a Front-end Form Submission
            Craft::dd($event->sender);
        }

        if (Craft::$app->request->isCpRequest)
        {
            // A Form Entry Element has been updated from the Control Panel

            Craft::dd($event->sender);
        }
    });
}
```

You can access the specific Form Entry Element being submitted via the `$event->sender` property.

Comment: Could you expand the example to show how to interact with the entry/form itself? I've tried `$event->entry` and `$event->params['entry']`, but neither works.

Comment: @peirix I realize my first example was for a Form Element not a Form Entry Element. I've updated the example and added bit more info on where you can find the Element in the event.